# Find document matching to all the provided parameters in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have documents in collection bookDetails,

```
doc1: {'bookData':{'bookName':'lotr','bookPart':'Part 3'}, 'library_name':'omega','libraryId':12166}

doc2: {'bookData':{'bookName':'hp','bookPart':'Part 7'}, 'library_name':'omega','libraryId':12199}

doc3: {'bookData':{'bookName':'hertu','bookPart':'Part 7'}, 'library_name':'omega','libraryId':9999}
```

I want to fetch only document which matches with all fields library name: omega, library id: 12199 and bookName: hp.

For this I tried as:

await collection.aggregate([{ $match: { library_name: 'omega' } }, ]).exec();{ $match: { libraryId: 12199 } }

But I also want to match with bookname : 'hp', so I can get required document.

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: you can put all the conditions together in single match stage `{ $match: { library_name: 'omega', libraryId: 12199, bookName: "hp" } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/C2EP96CkIRo

```
db.collection.find({
  library_name: "omega",
  libraryId: 12199,
  "bookData.bookName": "hp"
})
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/9mf9Sp8C4u6

With aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      library_name: "omega",
      libraryId: 12199,
      "bookData.bookName": "hp"
    }
  }
])
```